# Stockfish crashes on fen string

Tags: stockfish

I have created a GUI that communicates with a Stockfish 8 engine by passing it a FEN string. Everything works nice but on some specific FEN strings, Stockfish crashes. I don't have any clue why...

One of the FEN strings on which Stockfish crashes is

```
r2k1b1r/pp4p1/4QnPp/3p1B1P/2pPp3/3qP2N/5PKR/3nB3 b KQkq - 0 1
```

Comment: I don't know whether this is the reason, but since both kings have moved already castling should not be allowed anymore for either side. "KQkq" should be "-"

Comment: Note that a program shouldn't crash on invalid input. It should return an error message or fail somehow, but not crash.

Comment: Following up on Federico's comment... Is this an interface that a regular user could send a FEN to or this is a programmer only interface and you are expected to check the validity of the FEN beforehand? Also, by crash, do you really mean "crash"?

Comment: @user1583209 developer only

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, your FEN is absolutely invalid. You shouldn't give castling rights in a position that you kings have already moved. This won't work.

Comment: Ok i get it, but why it crashes on FEN where I have turned castling off for both sides E.g., it crashes on r4k2/3b1pp1/3bp1r1/1p1p4/pPpPnP1P/P1PqPN1N/6K1/R1B2Q1R b - - 0 1

Comment: @MohdWaseem Pls post that one in your question?

Comment: is anything wrong in FEN r4k2/3b1pp1/3bp1r1/1p1p4/pPpPnP1P/P1PqPN1N/6K1/R1B2Q1R b - - 0 1

Comment: @MohdWaseem Do you know how to play chess? Are you hired for a chess job that you know nothing about?

Comment: @MohdWaseem Do you know it's illegal to capture the king in check? I suggest you grab a chess book and learn the rules. You're wasting time unless you know the rules.

Comment: @MohdWaseem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_chess Study the chess rules. Learn it.